# How to check if a tab has been reloaded in background.js?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, listener

I am writing a Chrome extension which needs to detect if the tab has been reloaded, that is to say, the user refreshed the page (either by pressing the refresh button, or put a cursor behind the URL and press Enter) with no URL change. If it happens, then I will reinitialize my variables defined in *background.js*.

I am wondering how could I get this "`is_reload`" boolean value? I tried to make use of `windows.performance.navigation.type`, but it doesn't have any effect in the *background.js*.

Comment: Need more information. Do you have any content scripts running in that tab? If yes, how are they injected? Are you currently using `tabs` or `webNavigation` APIs?

Comment: It'd be quite easy to implement using an object with keys as tabId and a tab URL as the value, which is checked/updated in chrome.tabs.onUpdated event listener, but there are various edge cases that depend on whether you use an event page or a persistent background page.

Comment: @Xan I did not use any contents scripts, only background.js and popup.js. I am not familiar with content.js so for now just wanna keep it simple..

Comment: @wOxxOm i did not specify details of my background.js so i suppose it is persistent?

Comment: It's persistent by default, yes. A simplified demo of the approach I suggested: [Get previous url from chrome.tabs.onUpdated](//stackoverflow.com/a/33771228)

Answer (score 5):

### Use [`webNavigation`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation)

The API to use from a script in the background context to determine when a page is actually reloaded, not just the URL being updated in-page without navigation, is [`webNavigation`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation). You may want a [`webNavigation.onCommitted`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onCommitted) listener, which is the only event which has information as to *why* the page is navigating ([`transitionType`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#property-details-transitionQualifiers) and [`transitionQualifiers`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#property-details-transitionQualifiers)), but [`webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onDOMContentLoaded) or [`webNavigation.onCompleted`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onCompleted) will also work, depending on what your actual needs are.

If your goal really is to determine that it's a reload, not just a load, you will either need to keep a record of the current URL for each tab and compare the new URL against the old one, or use the [`TransitionType`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#type-TransitionType) Object contained in the `webNavigation.onCommitted`'s `transitionType` property, which will explicitly declare it a `"reload"`.

These are the events which occur when you reload a tab by clicking on the "reload this page" button:

```json
webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate    ->  arg[0]= {"frameId":0,"parentFrameId":-1,"processId":-1,"tabId":411,"timeStamp":1500401223978.314,"url":"http://www.example.com/"}        
webRequest.onBeforeRequest        ->  arg[0]= {"frameId":0,"method":"GET","parentFrameId":-1,"requestId":"260870","tabId":411,"timeStamp":1500401223979.044,"type":"main_frame","url":"http://www.example.com/"}        
webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders    ->  arg[0]= {"frameId":0,"method":"GET","parentFrameId":-1,"requestHeaders":[{"name":"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests","value":"1"},{"name":"User-Agent","value":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"},{"name":"Accept","value":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"},{"name":"Accept-Encoding","value":"gzip, deflate"},{"name":"Accept-Language","value":"en-US,en;q=0.8"}],"requestId":"260870","tabId":411,"timeStamp":1500401223979.3242,"type":"main_frame","url":"http://www.example.com/"}        
webRequest.onSendHeaders          ->  arg[0]= {"frameId":0,"method":"GET","parentFrameId":-1,"requestHeaders":[{"name":"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests","value":"1"},{"name":"User-Agent","value":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"},{"name":"Accept","value":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"},{"name":"Accept-Encoding","value":"gzip, deflate"},{"name":"Accept-Language","value":"en-US,en;q=0.8"}],"requestId":"260870","tabId":411,"timeStamp":1500401223979.538,"type":"main_frame","url":"http://www.example.com/"}        
webRequest.onHeadersReceived      ->  arg[0]= {"frameId":0,"method":"GET","parentFrameId":-1,"requestId":"260870","responseHeaders":[{"name":"Content-Encoding","value":"gzip"},{"name":"Accept-Ranges","value":"bytes"},{"name":"Cache-Control","value":"max-age=604800"},{"name":"Content-Type","value":"text/html"},{"name":"Date","value":"Tue, 18 Jul 2017 18:07:03 GMT"},{"name":"Etag","value":"\"359670651\""},{"name":"Expires","value":"Tue, 25 Jul 2017 18:07:03 GMT"},{"name":"Last-Modified","value":"Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT"},{"name":"Server","value":"ECS (rhv/818F)"},{"name":"Vary","value":"Accept-Encoding"},{"name":"X-Cache","value":"HIT"},{"name":"Content-Length","value":"606"}],"statusCode":200,"statusLine":"HTTP/1.1 200 OK","tabId":411,"timeStamp":1500401224072.296,"type":"main_frame","url":"http://www.example.com/"}        
webRequest.onResponseStarted      ->  arg[0]= {"frameId":0,"fromCache":false,"ip":"93.184.216.34","method":"GET","parentFrameId":-1,"requestId":"260870","responseHeaders":[{"name":"Content-Encoding","value":"gzip"},{"name":"Accept-Ranges","value":"bytes"},{"name":"Cache-Control","value":"max-age=604800"},{"name":"Content-Type","value":"text/html"},{"name":"Date","value":"Tue, 18 Jul 2017 18:07:03 GMT"},{"name":"Etag","value":"\"359670651\""},{"name":"Expires","value":"Tue, 25 Jul 2017 18:07:03 GMT"},{"name":"Last-Modified","value":"Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT"},{"name":"Server","value":"ECS (rhv/818F)"},{"name":"Vary","value":"Accept-Encoding"},{"name":"X-Cache","value":"HIT"},{"name":"Content-Length","value":"606"}],"statusCode":200,"statusLine":"HTTP/1.1 200 OK","tabId":411,"timeStamp":1500401224072.5032,"type":"main_frame","url":"http://www.example.com/"}        
webRequest.onCompleted            ->  arg[0]= {"frameId":0,"fromCache":false,"ip":"93.184.216.34","method":"GET","parentFrameId":-1,"requestId":"260870","responseHeaders":[{"name":"Content-Encoding","value":"gzip"},{"name":"Accept-Ranges","value":"bytes"},{"name":"Cache-Control","value":"max-age=604800"},{"name":"Content-Type","value":"text/html"},{"name":"Date","value":"Tue, 18 Jul 2017 18:07:03 GMT"},{"name":"Etag","value":"\"359670651\""},{"name":"Expires","value":"Tue, 25 Jul 2017 18:07:03 GMT"},{"name":"Last-Modified","value":"Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT"},{"name":"Server","value":"ECS (rhv/818F)"},{"name":"Vary","value":"Accept-Encoding"},{"name":"X-Cache","value":"HIT"},{"name":"Content-Length","value":"606"}],"statusCode":200,"statusLine":"HTTP/1.1 200 OK","tabId":411,"timeStamp":1500401224074.0261,"type":"main_frame","url":"http://www.example.com/"}        
tabs.onUpdated                    ->  arg[0]= 411 :: arg[1]= {"status":"loading","url":"http://www.example.com/"} :: arg[2]= {"active":true,"audible":false,"autoDiscardable":true,"discarded":false,"height":902,"highlighted":true,"id":411,"incognito":false,"index":1,"mutedInfo":{"muted":false},"pinned":false,"selected":true,"status":"loading","title":"www.example.com","url":"http://www.example.com/","width":1282,"windowId":10}    
tabs.onZoomChange                 ->  arg[0]= {"newZoomFactor":1,"oldZoomFactor":1,"tabId":411,"zoomSettings":{"mode":"automatic","scope":"per-origin"}}        
webNavigation.onCommitted         ->  arg[0]= {"frameId":0,"processId":107,"tabId":411,"timeStamp":1500401224079.4019,"transitionQualifiers":[],"transitionType":"reload","url":"http://www.example.com/"}
--->>Here is where you can tell it's a reload --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
history.onVisited                 ->  arg[0]= {"id":"42","lastVisitTime":1500401224077.579,"title":"Example Domain","typedCount":1,"url":"http://www.example.com/","visitCount":12}        
tabs.onUpdated                    ->  arg[0]= 411 :: arg[1]= {"title":"Example Domain"} :: arg[2]= {"active":true,"audible":false,"autoDiscardable":true,"discarded":false,"height":902,"highlighted":true,"id":411,"incognito":false,"index":1,"mutedInfo":{"muted":false},"pinned":false,"selected":true,"status":"loading","title":"Example Domain","url":"http://www.example.com/","width":1282,"windowId":10}    
webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded  ->  arg[0]= {"frameId":0,"processId":107,"tabId":411,"timeStamp":1500401224093.404,"url":"http://www.example.com/"}        
webNavigation.onCompleted         ->  arg[0]= {"frameId":0,"processId":107,"tabId":411,"timeStamp":1500401224094.768,"url":"http://www.example.com/"}        
tabs.onUpdated                    ->  arg[0]= 411 :: arg[1]= {"status":"complete"} :: arg[2]= {"active":true,"audible":false,"autoDiscardable":true,"discarded":false,"height":902,"highlighted":true,"id":411,"incognito":false,"index":1,"mutedInfo":{"muted":false},"pinned":false,"selected":true,"status":"complete","title":"Example Domain","url":"http://www.example.com/","width":1282,"windowId":10}
```

Here are the events for when the user selects the address bar and hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```json
webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate   ->  arg[0]= {"frameId":0,"parentFrameId":-1,"processId":-1,"tabId":411,"timeStamp":1500403090082.833,"url":"http://www.example.com/"}        
webRequest.onBeforeRequest       ->  arg[0]= {"frameId":0,"method":"GET","parentFrameId":-1,"requestId":"261350","tabId":411,"timeStamp":1500403090083.163,"type":"main_frame","url":"http://www.example.com/"}        
webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders   ->  arg[0]= {"frameId":0,"method":"GET","parentFrameId":-1,"requestHeaders":[{"name":"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests","value":"1"},{"name":"User-Agent","value":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"},{"name":"Accept","value":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"},{"name":"Accept-Encoding","value":"gzip, deflate"},{"name":"Accept-Language","value":"en-US,en;q=0.8"}],"requestId":"261350","tabId":411,"timeStamp":1500403090083.3289,"type":"main_frame","url":"http://www.example.com/"}        
webRequest.onSendHeaders         ->  arg[0]= {"frameId":0,"method":"GET","parentFrameId":-1,"requestHeaders":[{"name":"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests","value":"1"},{"name":"User-Agent","value":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"},{"name":"Accept","value":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"},{"name":"Accept-Encoding","value":"gzip, deflate"},{"name":"Accept-Language","value":"en-US,en;q=0.8"}],"requestId":"261350","tabId":411,"timeStamp":1500403090083.4739,"type":"main_frame","url":"http://www.example.com/"}        
webRequest.onHeadersReceived     ->  arg[0]= {"frameId":0,"method":"GET","parentFrameId":-1,"requestId":"261350","responseHeaders":[{"name":"Accept-Ranges","value":"bytes"},{"name":"Cache-Control","value":"max-age=604800"},{"name":"Date","value":"Tue, 18 Jul 2017 18:38:09 GMT"},{"name":"Expires","value":"Tue, 25 Jul 2017 18:38:09 GMT"},{"name":"Last-Modified","value":"Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT"},{"name":"Server","value":"ECS (rhv/818F)"},{"name":"Vary","value":"Accept-Encoding"},{"name":"X-Cache","value":"HIT"},{"name":"Content-Encoding","value":"gzip"},{"name":"Content-Type","value":"text/html"},{"name":"Etag","value":"\"359670651\""},{"name":"Content-Length","value":"606"}],"statusCode":200,"statusLine":"HTTP/1.1 200 OK","tabId":411,"timeStamp":1500403090130.209,"type":"main_frame","url":"http://www.example.com/"}        
webRequest.onResponseStarted     ->  arg[0]= {"frameId":0,"fromCache":true,"ip":"93.184.216.34","method":"GET","parentFrameId":-1,"requestId":"261350","responseHeaders":[{"name":"Accept-Ranges","value":"bytes"},{"name":"Cache-Control","value":"max-age=604800"},{"name":"Date","value":"Tue, 18 Jul 2017 18:38:09 GMT"},{"name":"Expires","value":"Tue, 25 Jul 2017 18:38:09 GMT"},{"name":"Last-Modified","value":"Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT"},{"name":"Server","value":"ECS (rhv/818F)"},{"name":"Vary","value":"Accept-Encoding"},{"name":"X-Cache","value":"HIT"},{"name":"Content-Encoding","value":"gzip"},{"name":"Content-Type","value":"text/html"},{"name":"Etag","value":"\"359670651\""},{"name":"Content-Length","value":"606"}],"statusCode":200,"statusLine":"HTTP/1.1 200 OK","tabId":411,"timeStamp":1500403090130.3289,"type":"main_frame","url":"http://www.example.com/"}        
webRequest.onCompleted           ->  arg[0]= {"frameId":0,"fromCache":true,"ip":"93.184.216.34","method":"GET","parentFrameId":-1,"requestId":"261350","responseHeaders":[{"name":"Accept-Ranges","value":"bytes"},{"name":"Cache-Control","value":"max-age=604800"},{"name":"Date","value":"Tue, 18 Jul 2017 18:38:09 GMT"},{"name":"Expires","value":"Tue, 25 Jul 2017 18:38:09 GMT"},{"name":"Last-Modified","value":"Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT"},{"name":"Server","value":"ECS (rhv/818F)"},{"name":"Vary","value":"Accept-Encoding"},{"name":"X-Cache","value":"HIT"},{"name":"Content-Encoding","value":"gzip"},{"name":"Content-Type","value":"text/html"},{"name":"Etag","value":"\"359670651\""},{"name":"Content-Length","value":"606"}],"statusCode":200,"statusLine":"HTTP/1.1 200 OK","tabId":411,"timeStamp":1500403090131.1592,"type":"main_frame","url":"http://www.example.com/"}        
tabs.onUpdated                   ->  arg[0]= 411 :: arg[1]= {"status":"loading"} :: arg[2]= {"active":true,"audible":false,"autoDiscardable":true,"discarded":false,"height":902,"highlighted":true,"id":411,"incognito":false,"index":1,"mutedInfo":{"muted":false},"pinned":false,"selected":true,"status":"loading","title":"Example Domain","url":"http://www.example.com/","width":1282,"windowId":10}    
tabs.onZoomChange                ->  arg[0]= {"newZoomFactor":1,"oldZoomFactor":1,"tabId":411,"zoomSettings":{"mode":"automatic","scope":"per-origin"}}        
webNavigation.onCommitted        ->  arg[0]= {"frameId":0,"processId":107,"tabId":411,"timeStamp":1500403090135.629,"transitionQualifiers":["from_address_bar"],"transitionType":"reload","url":"http://www.example.com/"}        
--->>Here is where you can tell it's a reload ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
--->>This tells you it was the user hitting [Enter] in the address bar----------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
history.onVisited                ->  arg[0]= {"id":"42","lastVisitTime":1500403090134.133,"title":"Example Domain","typedCount":1,"url":"http://www.example.com/","visitCount":12}        
webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded ->  arg[0]= {"frameId":0,"processId":107,"tabId":411,"timeStamp":1500403090144.5688,"url":"http://www.example.com/"}        
webNavigation.onCompleted        ->  arg[0]= {"frameId":0,"processId":107,"tabId":411,"timeStamp":1500403090146.102,"url":"http://www.example.com/"}        
tabs.onUpdated                   ->  arg[0]= 411 :: arg[1]= {"status":"complete"} :: arg[2]= {"active":true,"audible":false,"autoDiscardable":true,"discarded":false,"height":902,"highlighted":true,"id":411,"incognito":false,"index":1,"mutedInfo":{"muted":false},"pinned":false,"selected":true,"status":"complete","title":"Example Domain","url":"http://www.example.com/","width":1282,"windowId":10}
```

### Alternately, use a content script to tell the background script the page has reloaded

You can use a content script, defined in a [`content_scripts`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration) entry in your [*manifest.json*](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest), which is injected into the domains you desire to detect are loaded/reloaded. Each time the content script is run it can send a message, using [`runtime.sendMessage()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage), to the background script (received in a [`runtime.onMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage) listener) telling the background script that the page has been loaded/reloaded.

If you're monitoring a limited number of domains, this would be preferable, as the warning the user gets upon installing the extension will only state that the extension will have access to the specified domains, instead of all domains.

Answer (score 1):

Makyen answer is good!
Just some code snippet that worked for me!

```
// --- On Reloading or Entering example.com --- 
chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener((details) => {
    if (["reload", "link", "typed", "generated"].includes(details.transitionType) &&
        details.url === "http://example.com/") {

        codeAfterReload();

        chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function onComplete() {

            codeAfterReloadAndFinishSomeLoading();

            chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.removeListener(onComplete);
        });
    }
});
```

For more transition types:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/history/#transition_types

enjoy :)