# Adding a listener to webNavigation, in a chrome extension's background script everytime a url matching a pattern is visited

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to add a listener in the `background.js` file of a chrome extension.
I want this listener to ideally be filtered only for url's matching, for example, `netflix.com/watch/`

First, I tried `chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener` ([link](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webNavigation/#event-onCompleted)), supplying an appropriate filter for the desired netflix URL. However, I've observed that this listener doesn't fire if the URL is navigated to via the browser's forward or backwards buttons. Also, it doesn't seem like the listener fires if the navigation originates from clicking a link on a webpage from the same domain (ie: clicking on a Netflix video while browsing or searching (taking you from netflix.com/browse to the targeted netflix.com/watch URL)).

I then tried `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` ([link](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#event-onUpdated)). This event fires with the backward/forward buttons, and also fires when navigating from a page of the same domain, but, it doesn't fire when refreshing the same page (since the tab doesn't change in this case). Preferably I would like to handle the refresh case as well.

I could use both listeners to cover each listener's omissions, but there are cases where both will fire at the same time, which isn't desirable.

Is there an event I can listen for that will cover all the situations I described?

Comment: Just use `tab.url.includes("host.com")` with `onUpdated`

Comment: @Rojo, I mentioned in my post that the event doesn't fire when navigating from the same domain. That was my issue with `onUpdated`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a tab has been reloaded in background.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45139926/how-to-check-if-a-tab-has-been-reloaded-in-background-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chrome.tabs.onUpdated is actually fired when refreshing a tab so your code is incorrect. I guess it looks for changeInfo.url which is not provided on refresh.

Look at `status` as well and use `url` or `pendingUrl` from the `tab` parameter:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, info, tab) => {
  if (info.url || info.status === 'loading') {
    const url = info.url || tab.pendingUrl || tab.url;
    console.log(url); // prints in the *background* console
  }
});
```

For [webNavigation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) with SPA (Single-Page Application) sites like netflix/youtube you need to listen to more events: onHistoryStateUpdated, onReferenceFragmentUpdated.