# Chrome Extension manifest V3 - Share General Functions Between Different Content Scripts

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I wanted to share "Extra Functions"/ "General Functions" between couple of content scripts.

```
// contentScript1.js
function myCode() {
    return 1 + 1;
}

function generalFunction(number) {
    return number * number;
}
```

```
// contentScript2.js
function differentCode() {
    return "man walking on the moon";
}

function generalFunction(number) {
    return number * number;
}
```

And didn't want to just maintain the same exact function in two different places.

Answer (score 1):

So I created a third content script.

```
// sharedFunctions.js
function generalFunction(number) {
    return number * number;
}
```

Injected it before injecting any other content script or once every page reload.

Content script ["live in an isolated world"](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#isolated_world), but they live in the same isolated world as other connect scripts (of the same extension)!

p.s. How to find out there is a page reload? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67191601/2593480